# Cardinal numbers bigger than $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In my set theory textbook it is left for an exercise to prove that all natural numbers and $\omega$ are cardinal numbers and that every other bigger ordinal number up to and including $\epsilon_0:=sup ${1, $\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, ...} is not a cardinal number.
I don't understand how can it be that we don't have any cardinals between $\omega$ and $\epsilon_0$, it seems like a huge gap. Also, there is a theorem that says there is a unique cardinal number $\alpha$ for every set a, such that $\alpha$ is equipotent with a. Does this mean that all ordinals from $\omega$ to $\epsilon_0$ are equipotent, i.e. belong to the same one equivalence class?

Comment: (1) [The next cardinal after $\omega$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number#Hartogs's_theorem) is [the least uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number#Aleph-one), but [$\epsilon_0$ is countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_number). (2) The theorem you quote indeed has the implication you suggest.

Comment: One of my Prof said , "while there are ordinal numbers between ω and ϵ0, there are no cardinal numbers in that range because the sets with ordinal numbers in that range do not have the same cardinality as ω or ϵ0."

Comment: The gap is a lot huger than that. $\epsilon_0$ is arguably the smallest [large countable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal)

Comment: I agree with you that the gap between $\omega$ and $\varepsilon_0$ seems huge. The lesson to learn from that is that countable sets, when suitably arranged, can indeed seem huge. Another example, in my opinion, is that the set of rational numbers, when visualized on the number line, looks way bigger than the set of integers, even though both are countable.

Answer (score 1):

The first uncountable ordinal, is the first cardinal number after $\omega$, everything in between is countable and therefore is not a cardinal number.